# Putting a button in center

Tags: html, css

I seem to have a difficulty in putting the button i made in the center of the screen. Here's the source code.

```
<a href="#" class="header-button">View Products</a>
```

Here are the styles

```
/*header button styles*/

a.header-button {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:#
}

a.header-button:hover {
    color: #e8ddc8;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.header-button {
    background-color:#031634;
    color:#e8ddc8;
    padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

You see, even though I put `text-align:center` in the `.header-button`, the button does not position itself at the center. (See image below)

[image]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Add `text-align:center` to a parent element. It will work then..

Comment: JoshC answer will work I believe but in case it doesn't margin:auto 0; probably could solve your problem

Comment: @gelolopez: as JoshC suggested,is what is my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M42M3/)

```
a.header-button {
    display: block;
    background-color:#;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution: http://jsfiddle.net/xzY5j/

css:

```
.header-button {
    background-color:#031634;
    color:#e8ddc8;
    padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.container {
    text-align:center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 50px;
    background-color:#ccc;
}
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="header-button">View Products</a>
</div>
```

Other suggestion is:
Binita Tamang solution she wrote it before I had a chance so I will let her get the credit for it :)

Answer (score 1):

You should give the container or the parent element `text-align:center`

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/S789p/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
<a href="#" class="header-button">View Products</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent{

 text-align:center;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put a `button` or any `element` on middle of the screen,then use position absolute an give the top 50% and left 50% now,give margin just half of its width and height in minus :

Something like this :

**CSS**

```
button{
        position:absolute;
        top:50%;
        left:50%;
        width:100px;
        height:30px;
        margin:-15px 0 0 -50px;
      }
```

And if only middle from left then :

```
button{
        position:absolute;
        top:some_top_in_px;
        left:50%;
        width:100px;
        height:30px;
        margin:0px 0 0 -50px;
      }
```

[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ashish41191/f4yvN/)

Comment: My only problem in absolute positioning is that it is so hard to manipulate when you are already in the midst of doing things.